# Unable to redirect after a user registers in Laravel Jetstream

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-jetstream

I am successfully able to redirect whenever a user logs in. I am using the Login Response method. But when I am trying to do the same thing for the user when a user registers, it shows the URL in the browser, but I need to refresh to view the page to make it load. Something weird thing is happening here.

Following the below approach:
https://talltips.novate.co.uk/laravel/laravel-8-conditional-login-redirects
To understand the problem, please check the gif below. Login Response is working the way I expected, but Register Response is not working; it is behaving weirdly.

**Login Response**

[image: Login Response]

**Register Response**

[image: Register Response]

**LoginResponse.php**

```php
namespace App\Http\Responses;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\LoginResponse as LoginResponseContract;

class LoginResponse implements LoginResponseContract
{
    public function toResponse($request)
    {
        if (Auth::user()->hasAnyRoles(['Administrator', 'Employee'])) {
            return redirect()->route('backend.dashboard');
        }

        return redirect()->route('frontend.dashboard');
    }
}
```

**RegisterResponse.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Responses;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\RegisterResponse as RegisterResponseContract;

class RegisterResponse implements RegisterResponseContract
{

    public function toResponse($request)
    {
        if(Auth::user()->hasAnyRoles(['Administrator', 'Employee'])) {
            return redirect()->route('backend.dashboard');
        }

        return redirect()->route('frontend.dashboard');
    }

}
```

**JetstreamServiceProvider.php**

```
public function boot() {
    $this - > configurePermissions();

    Jetstream::deleteUsersUsing(DeleteUser::class);

    // Register New LoginResponse
    $this - > app - > singleton(
        \Laravel\ Fortify\ Contracts\ LoginResponse::class,
        \App\ Http\ Responses\ LoginResponse::class);

    // Register New RegisterResponse
    $this - > app - > singleton(
        \Laravel\ Fortify\ Contracts\ RegisterResponse::class,
                \App\ Http\ Responses\ RegisterResponse::class);
}
```

**AuthServiceProvider.php**

```
public function boot() {
    $this - > registerPolicies();

    Gate::define('access-backend', function($user) {
        return $user - > hasAnyRoles(['Administrator', 'Employee']);
    });

    Gate::define('access-frontend', function($user) {
        return $user - > hasRole('Client');
    });
}
```

**Web.php**

```php
Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->group(function () {
    \
    Route::prefix('backend')->name('backend.')->middleware(['can:access-backend'])->group(function () {
            Route::get('/dashboard', \App\Http\Livewire\Backend\Dashboard::class)->name('dashboard');
        });
    Route::prefix('frontend')->name('frontend.')->middleware(['can:access-frontend'])->group(function () {
        Route::get('/dashboard', \App\Http\Livewire\Frontend\Dashboard::class)->name('dashboard');
    });
});
```

Comment: One observation is In your web routes, there is a glaring backslash "\" on line two.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Create your own **RegisterResponse.php**

```
use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;
use Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\RegisterResponse as Response;

class RegisterResponse implements Response
{
    public function toResponse($request)
    {
        return $request->wantsJson()
                        ? new JsonResponse('', 201)
                        : redirect(config('fortify.user'));
}
```

and register it in the `JetstreamServiceProvider.php` file, inside `boot` method

```
$this->app->singleton(
    \Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\RegisterResponse::class,
    \App\Http\Responses\RegisterResponse::class
);
```